# How to handle JavaScript in ASP.NET MVC3 when I click the delete button

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I have developed a small ASP.NET MVC 3 application in that I have an account application. When I click the delete button, it will ask in the confirmation window something like:

> "Are you sure you want delete this"?

How do I open this message box in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the button, place this attribute:

```
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');"
```

Comment: Hi thank you for giving response with solution..it is working for me..but one more issue when i use button action like this  <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>  How can i use that onclick ? please help me

Comment: You need to use a version of Html.ActionLink which accepts a dictionary object populated with your desired attributes. Something like that:

@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", null, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');" })

Comment: i have to use the TelerikMVC3 with Aspx application.Is there any image button click event? in this application. already i have write helper class for imageclick event but showing error can u guide me please...

Comment: I can't understand your question, sorry. Please try to submit code to demonstrate.

Comment: sorry, i have try to explain you what i want, i want Image click event  (in normal asp.net there is imagebutton like that) in mvc3 i want imageclick event ..

Comment: You should manually create an <a> (the ActionLink discussed above) and an <img> tag.